# Folder attributes lost on copy or move in Windows 10 1607 (Anniversary Update)

Tags: windows-10-v1607, windows-10-v1511, dir, attributes

Windows 10 1511

- Make copy of folder with attributes +R/+S on same partition - Copy has **same** attributes set
- Make copy of folder with attributes +R/+S on different partition - Copy has **same** attributes set
- Move folder with attributes +R/+S on same partition - Folder still has **same** attributes set
- Move folder with attributes +R/+S to different partition - Folder still has **same** attributes set

Windows 10 1607

- Make copy of folder with attributes +R/+S on same partition - Copy **loses** attributes
- Make copy of folder with attributes +R/+S on different partition - Copy **loses** attributes
- Move folder with attributes +R/+S on same partition - Folder still has **same** attributes set
- Move folder with attributes +R/+S to different partition - Folder **loses** attributes

---

1. Does this affect everyone? (Update: Seems to be the case. Given the comments below though, for anyone testing this behavior I repeat, please check for **folder** and not **file** attributes.)
2. Is it a bug or a deliberate change by Microsoft? (And if the latter, was it announced anywhere?)
3. Regardless of the answer to #2, is there any way to make 1607 behave the same as 1511?

Comment: I was unable to reproduce the behavior you describe

Comment: So 1607 behaves exactly like 1511 for you? Can you mention the exact editions and versions you tested on? 1511 (10586.589) and 1607 (14393.187) for me behave the way I've described above. Perhaps the change was introduced in a cumulative update.

Comment: The current version, Windows 10 build 14393.187, which is the current version as of today.  "So 1607 behaves exactly like 1511 for you?" - exactly the same.  I saw no point in trying Version 1511, because you can't reproduce the behavior on it, and its not the current version of Windows 10.  "Is it a bug or a deliberate change by Microsoft?" - its neither a bug or a feature change.

Comment: I create a Folder called Test, a file called Text.txt.  I set the +S +R on the file, created a copy of the folder, and then viewed the attributes on the new file that was created in the new folder.  The attributes were exactly the same.  This was the case if I created it in on the same partition or not.  This is basic NTFS behavior.

Comment: I also forced the update to 14393.221, the behavior was as expected, exactly like it always worked.

Comment: @Ramhound "I set the +S +R on the file, created a copy of the folder, and then viewed the attributes on the new file that was created in the new folder. The attributes were exactly the same. This was the case if I created it in on the same partition or not. This is basic NTFS behavior." - Yes, it IS basic NTFS behavior, but NOT at all relevant to this BUG. I don't know why you're setting the attributes of a FILE, when I specifically mentioned FOLDER attributes being lost.

Comment: I set the attributes for the files and folder. Be nice!

Comment: Hey, I'm as nice to others as they are towards me! To be frank I didn't appreciate the condescending tone of your "This is basic NTFS behavior" comment, but let's move on. You did not indicate that you set the folder attributes too. If you did and they were retained in all 8 test cases, I find that most puzzling because I've replicated this on all 1607 systems I tested, and moreover people on two separate forums have corroborated. Something's definitely up. Wonder what affected systems have in common (that is, if indeed not all are affected because so far 1607 seems to be fine only for you).

Comment: Just updated to 14393.222 (not .221), and it continues to display the same buggy behavior.

Answer (score 0):

Microsoft has acknowledged and fixed this Windows 10 **BUG** in Insider Preview build 15019. You can use [**llandyw**'s right-click solution](https://www.tenforums.com/customization/62151-problem-copying-customized-folders-2.html#post933529) till such time the fix is released to the general public.

Comment: If you have a solution, post the solution.  In general, including commentary detracts from the answer.  Commentary whose only purpose is to make a personal attack on another user is contrary to the site's fundamental rule to "be nice".